# Can somebody create a working (.net 4.5.1) Google calendar sample with push notification

Tags: google-api-dotnet-client

The google sample dosen't work. 
I can't find a working one.
Documentation is useless.

framework
.net 4.5.1

nuget

- DotNetOpenAuth 5.0.0-alpha1
- Google.Apis.Calendar.v3 -Version 1.5.0.65-beta
- Google.Apis.Authentication.OAuth2 -Version 1.2.4696.27634

first line first error

var provider = new NativeApplicationClient(GoogleAuthenticationServer.Description "id", "key");

module dotnetopenoauth, versio=4.0.0.111 should be referenced

I have tried so many frameorks and online example but work either.

Sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 0):

[Google.Apis.Authentication](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Apis.Authentication/) contains a reference to DotNetOpenAuth version 4.0.0.11.
You can start a new project (let's say command line) and add a NuGet reference to Google.Apis.Calendar.v3 and Google.Apis.Authentication.

That's exactly how our [Calendar.VB.ConsoleApp](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/source/browse/?repo=samples#hg/Calendar.VB.ConsoleApp) sample works.

Be aware that in the next days we are going to release a new version (1.6.0-beta), so you should subscribe to our announcements blog (http://google-api-dotnet-client.blogspot.com/) in order to keep you updated.

Comment: Two years later, there's still no sample using push notifications. Is this planned? Do you know of any external sample?

Comment: A lot happened in the last years. You can read about it in our blog, which is mentioned above. But.. we still don't have a support for push notifications. Since the project is open-source and was recently moved to github, github.com/google/google-api-dotnet-client, you can contribute add implement this by yourself. It will be well appreciated...

Comment: If I figure out how to make a clean sample implementation, I will contribute.